# Single machine server with many operating systems

Tags: ubuntu, networking, virtualization, firewall, router

Could possibly with single one high end Server with supported Virtualization
We can have: 
- DHCP Server (Virtual Machine 1), 
- Firewall (Virtual Machine 2), 
- Squid proxy (Virtual Machine 3)
- Database server (Virtual Machine 4)
All of them can run at once ? 
Any help suggestion would be greatly appreciate

Comment: High end server not needed, you could do that on a ropey old Core 2 Duo desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Of course you can do this.

Comment: Did you know other alternatif of vmware hypervisor in gnu or open source edition ?

Comment: @th3cl41 is something wrong with your browser that Google doesn't work?